# Sql INSERT into FILETABLE with OUTPUT parameter creates timeout and deadlock

Tags: sql, insert, timeout, output, deadlock

I have this command being executed in my .NET WebApi server after connection to my local sql database:

```
DECLARE @insertedID table (stream_id uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO FTPICTURE (name, file_stream) 
    OUTPUT inserted.stream_id into @insertedID
    VALUES(@name, @file_stream);

SELECT *
FROM @insertedID
```

With that command I can insert a picture file to my sql database stored in a filetable. The timeout and deadlock problem occurs when this statement is executed with two or more incoming requests. The first thread can execute the code normally and receives the stream_id from the inserted file through the insertedID object. The second thread then executes the code but has to wait for some reason I can't explain. First thread is continuing with the code until thread two throws the timeout expired error. Thread one calls the same function again, because a smaller version of the original is also being saved. But when executing the command again, it creates a deadlock.

I am using a transaction with no set Isolation level.

For some reason it appears to me, that when executing the command, the table is still being locked after the insert succeeded. I can't figure out why this is happening...